# Como usar switch em C?

Tags: c, switch

Tenho que entender este código que meu orientador me passou.

O `opt` depois de `switch` é obrigatório?

O comando `break` também? Por que ele não aparece depois das opções `case '?'` e `default`?

```
if( argc <= 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nparametros:\n-e arquivo de entrada\n-s arquivo de saida\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "e:s:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {

        case 's':
            saida=optarg;
            printf("Nome do arquivo de saida: %s\n", saida);
            errS++;
            break;

        case 'e':
            entrada=optarg;
            printf("Nome do arquivo de entrada: %s\n", entrada);
            errE++;
            break;


        case '?':
            fprintf(stderr, "\nFALTA PARAMETROS\n");

        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "%s \nparametros:\n-e arquivo de entrada\n-s arquivo de saida\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O "opt" depois de "switch" é obrigatório?

Bom, não. Ali é preciso uma expressão que dê algum valor que possa ser comparado com as opções de `case`. Geralmente é uma variável, mas não precisa ser, muito menos precisa ser `opt`. Pode, mas não faz sentido ter um literal, se você já sabe o valor não tem porque comparar.

O `switch` sempre pega este valor e descobre qual dos `case`s que se encaixa nele, só um pode ser executado de forma direta. Mas outros podem executar em sequência de forma indireta, então o `case` que ele entrar porque o seu literal (e no `case` sempre deve ter um literal) é igual ao valor do `switch` será o primeiro, depois ele continua entrando em todos os `case`s seguintes.

Isso ajuda porque muitas vezes você quer fazer uma espécie de `or`, ou seja, mais de um valor é aceito, qualquer um que ele entrar deve executar todos os blocos de execução a seguir. É comum que nestes casos só o último `case` que deve fazer alguma coisa ter um código, os demais ficam vazios, assim:

```
switch (variavel) {
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
    printf("entrou");
}
```

> O comando "break" também?

Mas fazer isso é pouco útil, você vai querer que ele pare de executar em algum momento, não pode mandar fazer todos porque aí o `switch` deixar de ser útil, você não está selecionando nada.

É aí que entra o `break`, você o usa para dizer que este bloco deve ser encerrado. Note que no momento que encontrar o `break` o `switch` todo é encerrado. Assim fica melhor:

```
switch (variavel) {
case 1:
case 3:
    printf("impar");
    break;
case 2:
case 4:
    printf("entrou");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Switch.c).

> Por que ele não aparece depois das opções "case '?' " e "default"?

Viu que eu não usei o `break` no final. Por que eu usaria? No final ele encerra mesmo. Não tem necessidade. Mas muitas pessoas colocam assim mesmo para organizar, deixar mais legível, identificar a intenção e facilitar uma mudança que adicione algum bloco sem correr o risco de esquecer de colocar o `break` que agora se torna necessário.

O mesmo vale para o `default`, não tem porque mandar encerrar algo que está encerrando.

Pode se perguntar porque o último `case` não precisou do `break` sendo que existe o `default` em seguida. O `default` é especial, só entra nela se não entrar nos blocos anteriores, ele é é um OU de execução, não tem como entrar nela se entrou em algum `case`. É outro nome, o compilador sabe que encerrou antes.

No `default` ninguém coloca `break` não faz sentido por nenhum ponto de vista são.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Só duas dúvidas:
1) "Pode, mas não faz sentido ter um literal" o que quer dizer  literal neste contexto?
2) "O switch sempre ga este valor e descobre qual os case que se encaixa nele, só um pode ser executado de forma direta" Não entendi sua frase, o que é este 'ga'?

Comment: Literal é o valor mesmo, um número, um texto, não é uma variável, constante, expressão. Arrumei o texto

Answer (score 2):

**O "opt" depois de "switch" é obrigatório?**

Sim, é obrigatório, primeiro porque sem ele o comando não funciona, segundo porque a variável "opt" contem o valor que eventualmente vai corresponder ao valor contido em algum dos cases. Se os valores corresponderem, o bloco de código é executado.

**O comando "break" também? Por que ele não aparece depois das opções "case" e "default"?**

O comando break não é obrigatório, mas ele é utilizado para quebrar o fluxo de execução. O default é ativado somente se não houver nenhuma correspondência, e o case "?" é ativado somente quando a entrada dos dados é inválida. Em ambos os casos não ha necessidade de interromper a execução do programa.

Comment: Obrigado. Então basicamente tem as opções "e" e "s", se eu digitar "d" a opção "?" será adotada?

Comment: O comando recebe o valor (no caso, string) que eu digitar?
Ou seja, terei que digitar "e" ou "s"?

Comment: No caso, ainda tem algumas linhas de comando acima que eu omiti:

if( argc <= 1) {

  fprintf(stderr, "\nparametros:\n-e arquivo de entrada\n-s arquivo de saida\n");

  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "e:s:")) != -1) {

Comment: Acho que a opção "?" é executada quando a entrada é vazia. Tem que dar uma olhada na função getopt para ver o que ela retorna.

Comment: Sim, o comando só executado quando há correspondência entre o valor do switch e do case

Comment: Entendi! EUREKA! Hahaha. A variável "opt" tem que ter valor antes de entra no "switch". Consegui rodar. Achei que apareceriam as mensagens (cases) e depois eu digitaria a letra que fosse conveniente. Consegui entender este comando "switch", muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Answer (score 2):

`switch(opt)` informa que a variável `opt` será usada para comparar com os valores depois de cada `case`.

Cada `break` sinaliza que o controle deve sair fora do bloco `switch`. Então, apesar de não ser obrigatório, seria bom se tivesse um `break` no final dos comandos do `case '?'`.

`default` é usado para as expressões não cobertas pelos `cases` declarados anteriormente. Como é o último caso, não precisa do `break` para sair do bloco `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

O Operador **opt** é uma variável, sim é necessário é como se fosse um **if()** ao colocar ele lá ele vai pegar o valor dessa essa variável e  comparar com os **CASE** caso não encontre nada vai cair no **DEFAULT**

o **Break** é e não é necessário, ele serve pra barra o processo exemplo:

```
switch(num)
{

case 1:
x = i;
printf("Olha eu aqui");

case 2:
x = 20;
printf("Olha eu aqui");
break;
}
```

Neste caso o primeiro **case 1** vai continuar pro case 2 e vai soltar dois **printf** pois não existe o **Break** no case 1

Comment: Seu exemplo ajudou! Obrigado!