# Loop infinito no switch

Tags: c++, loop, switch

O problema é que nos 3 casos, o `cout` repete infinitamente.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<locale.h>

    int main(){
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
        bool a;
        int consumo;
        cout << "Digite 1 -> até 100kw" << endl;
        cout << "Digite 2 -> de 101kw até 200kw" << endl;
        cout << "Digite 3 -> maior que 200kw" << endl;
        cin >> consumo;
        while(true){
             switch(consumo){
                case 1:
                    cout << "Parabéns, você é econômico." << endl;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "Cuidado, você está gastando muito." << endl;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "Que isso vei?" << endl;
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Valor inválido, tente novamente." << endl;
                    cout << "Digite 1 -> até 100kw" << endl;
                    cout << "Digite 2 -> de 101kw até 200kw" << endl;
                    cout << "Digite 3 -> maior que 200kw" << endl;
                    cin >> consumo;
                    continue;
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

O `switch` não funciona assim eu [já respondi sobre o problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/282675/101). O `break` não funciona como quebra do laço quando ele está dentro do `case`, não pode usá-lo. Mais sobre: [Break e Continue no Switch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318636/101).

Você pode refazer esse código colocando um `if` para saber se deve sair ou não ou pode usar um `goto`, o que [muitos se arrepiam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101), mas não tem problema algum.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    while (true) {
        int consumo;
        cout << "Digite 1 -> até 100kw" << endl;
        cout << "Digite 2 -> de 101kw até 200kw" << endl;
        cout << "Digite 3 -> maior que 200kw" << endl;
        cin >> consumo;
        switch (consumo) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Parabéns, você é econômico." << endl;
            goto fim;
        case 2:
            cout << "Cuidado, você está gastando muito." << endl;
            goto fim;
        case 3:
            cout << "Que isso vei?" << endl;
            goto fim;
        }
    }
fim:
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fatvoT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qhxcwxku-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SwitchBreakGoto.c).

Ou pode fazer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    while (true) {
        int consumo;
        cout << "Digite 1 -> até 100kw" << endl;
        cout << "Digite 2 -> de 101kw até 200kw" << endl;
        cout << "Digite 3 -> maior que 200kw" << endl;
        cin >> consumo;
        switch (consumo) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Parabéns, você é econômico." << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Cuidado, você está gastando muito." << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Que isso vei?" << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (consumo > 0 && consumo < 4) break;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OpTLyq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sqcxwllr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/SwitchBreakIf.c).

Ainda dá para fazer com uma variável *flag*, como parece que ia fazer, mas eu acho bem ruim adicionar estado para controlar isso.

Uma última forma que não é exatamente ruim, mas provavelmente um tiquinho de nada mais lento, o que não faz a menor diferença em caso assim, é trocar o `switch` por `if`s.

Aproveitei para eliminar a duplicação desnecessária de código.

Answer (score 0):

Obviamente que vai ser loop infinito, fora do switch está o  `while(true)` sem qualquer tipo de `break`, basta tirar isso que resolve o problema.

Pode tambem adicionar o `break;` depois do switch caso queira manter o `while(true)`

```
switch(consumo){
                case 1:
                    cout << "Parabéns, você é econômico." << endl;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << "Cuidado, você está gastando muito." << endl;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << "Que isso vei?" << endl;
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Valor inválido, tente novamente." << endl;
                    cout << "Digite 1 -> até 100kw" << endl;
                    cout << "Digite 2 -> de 101kw até 200kw" << endl;
                    cout << "Digite 3 -> maior que 200kw" << endl;
                    cin >> consumo;
                    continue;
            }break;
```

Precisa de um `break` para parar o `switch` e outro `break` para parar o `while`

Comment: Mas isso não faz o que ele quer. Na verdade o código tem erros.

Comment: Adicionando o `break` penso que resolve o problema e que faça o que ele quer.

Comment: mas se tiver um laço que tem um `break` não condicional e não ter o laço executa a mesma coisa.

Comment: deu certo aqui desse jeito

Comment: Não percebi o que quis dizer, aquele break serve para concluir o processo caso dê tudo certo, caso digite outro valor que nao o esperado continua no loop....