# Quando executo os comandos no Switch Case, ele encerra ao invés de voltar ao Menu?

Tags: c, switch, case

```
int main(){
    int tensao, corrente, resistencia, potencia, tempo, cargaeletrica, trabalho, i;

    printf("\nPara calculo de Tensao(resistencia*corrente) digite 1\n\nPara calculo de Potencia(tensao*corrente) digite 2\n\nPara calculo de Corrente(carga eletrica/tempo) digite 3\n\nPara calculo de Tensao de outra Maneira(trabalho/carga eletrica) digite 4\n\nPara calculo de Potencia de Outra Maneira(resistencia*corrente^2) digite 5\n\nPara calculo de Potencia de Outra Maneira(tensao^2/resistencia) digite 6\n\nDigite 7 para sair do Menu!\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    switch (i){
    case 1:
        printf("Determine o valor de Corrente: ");
        scanf("%d", &corrente);
        printf("Determine o valor de Resistencia: ");
        scanf("%d", &resistencia);
        tensao = resistencia*corrente;
        printf("Valor da Tensao: %d", tensao);
    break;

    case 2:
        printf("Determine o valor de Tensao: ");
        scanf("%d", &tensao);
        printf("Determine o valor de Corrente: ");
        scanf("%d", &corrente);
        potencia = tensao*corrente;
        printf("Valor da Potencia: %d", potencia);
    break;

    case 3:
        printf("Determine o valor de Carga Eletrica: ");
        scanf("%d", &cargaeletrica);
        printf("Determine o valor de Tempo: ");
        scanf("%d", &tempo);
        corrente = cargaeletrica/tempo;
        printf("Valor da Corrente: %d", corrente);
    break;

    case 4:
        printf("Determine o valor de Trabalho: ");
        scanf("%d", &trabalho);
        printf("Determine o valor de Carga Eletrica: ");
        scanf("%d", &cargaeletrica);
        tensao = trabalho/cargaeletrica;
        printf("Valor da Tensao: %d", tensao);
    break;

    case 5:
        printf("Determine o valor de Resistencia: ");
        scanf("%d", &resistencia);
        printf("Determine o valor de Corrente: ");
        scanf("%d", &corrente);
        potencia = resistencia*pow(corrente,2);
        printf("Valor da Potencia: %d", potencia);
    break;

    case 6:
        printf("Determine o valor de Tensao: ");
        scanf("%d", &tensao);
        printf("Determine o valor de Resistencia: ");
        scanf("%d", &resistencia);
        potencia = pow(tensao,2)/resistencia;
        printf("Valor da Potencia: %d", potencia);
    break;

    default:
        printf("Valor Invalido!");

    case 7:
        break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Porque não haveria de fechar? Como seria suposto o programa voltar ao menu?

Comment: tu tem que utilizar um laço de repetição como exemplificado abaixo pelo @Rogi93

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar que o programa encerre,uma das alternativas é utilizar a estrutura de repetição `while` com uma condição que se refira a opção de sair `while(i != 7)`. Para evitar que o prompt fique lotado de informações a cada laço, a função `system("cls")`pode ser utilizada para limpara a tela a cada laço, gerando um efeito mais agradavel.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int tensao; 
int corrente;
int resistencia; 
int potencia; 
int tempo; 
int cargaeletrica; 
int trabalho; 
int i = 0;


while(i != 7){

    system("cls");
    printf("\nPara calculo de Tensao(resistencia*corrente) digite 1\n\nPara calculo de Potencia(tensao*corrente) digite 2"
           "\n\nPara calculo de Corrente(carga eletrica/tempo) digite 3"
           "\n\nPara calculo de Tensao de outra Maneira(trabalho/carga eletrica) digite 4"
           "\n\nPara calculo de Potencia de Outra Maneira(resistencia*corrente^2) digite 5"
           "\n\nPara calculo de Potencia de Outra Maneira(tensao^2/resistencia) digite 6"
           "\n\nDigite 7 para sair do Menu!\n\n"
           "Opcao desejada:");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    switch (i){
        case 1:
            printf("Determine o valor de Corrente: ");
            scanf("%d", &corrente);
            printf("Determine o valor de Resistencia: ");
            scanf("%d", &resistencia);
            tensao = resistencia*corrente;
            printf("Valor da Tensao: %d\n", tensao);
            system("PAUSE");
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("Determine o valor de Tensao: ");
            scanf("%d", &tensao);
            printf("Determine o valor de Corrente: ");
            scanf("%d", &corrente);
            potencia = tensao*corrente;
            printf("Valor da Potencia: %d\n", potencia);
            system("PAUSE");
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("Determine o valor de Carga Eletrica: ");
            scanf("%d", &cargaeletrica);
            printf("Determine o valor de Tempo: ");
            scanf("%d", &tempo);
            corrente = cargaeletrica/tempo;
            printf("Valor da Corrente: %d\n", corrente);
            system("PAUSE");
            break;

        case 4:
            printf("Determine o valor de Trabalho: ");
            scanf("%d", &trabalho);
            printf("Determine o valor de Carga Eletrica: ");
            scanf("%d", &cargaeletrica);
            tensao = trabalho/cargaeletrica;
            printf("Valor da Tensao: %d\n", tensao);
            system("PAUSE");
            break;

        case 5:
            printf("Determine o valor de Resistencia: ");
            scanf("%d", &resistencia);
            printf("Determine o valor de Corrente: ");
            scanf("%d", &corrente);
            potencia = resistencia*pow(corrente,2);
            printf("Valor da Potencia: %d\n", potencia);
            system("PAUSE");
            break;

        case 6:
            printf("Determine o valor de Tensao: ");
            scanf("%d", &tensao);
            printf("Determine o valor de Resistencia: ");
            scanf("%d", &resistencia);
            potencia = pow(tensao,2)/resistencia;
            printf("Valor da Potencia: %d\n", potencia);
            system("PAUSE");
            break;

        case 7:
            break;

        default:
            printf("Valor Invalido!\n");
            system("PAUSE");

      }

 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Para voltar para o menu seria necessario um ciclo ou mesmo usar a função [**goto**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_goto_statement.htm), ao usar um ciclo tinha de colocar fora do `switch` e só quando carregar na tecla 7 é que sai desse tal ciclo.
O `break` faz ele sair de todo o `switch{}` e por isso termina o programa.

Deixo referencia ao [**break**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/318636/break-e-continue-no-switch)

Como por exemplo:

```
/*(...)*/
while(1)
{
  printf("\nPara calculo de Tensao(resistencia*corrente) digite 1\n\nPara calculo de Potencia(tensao*corrente) digite 2\n\nPara calculo de Corrente(carga eletrica/tempo) digite 3\n\nPara calculo de Tensao de outra Maneira(trabalho/carga eletrica) digite 4\n\nPara calculo de Potencia de Outra Maneira(resistencia*corrente^2) digite 5\n\nPara calculo de Potencia de Outra Maneira(tensao^2/resistencia) digite 6\n\nDigite 7 para sair do Menu!\n\n");
  scanf("%d", &i);
  switch(i){
  /*(...)*/
   case 7:
    break;
   default:
    printf("Valor Invalido!");
    break;
  }
if(i==7)
  break;
//limpar tela
}
```

Para ficar mais bonito, deverá limpar, pode usar bastantes funções para fazer esse clean, faço referencia ao [**StackOverflowEN**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347770/how-do-you-clear-the-console-screen-in-c).

Usando a função `goto`

```
 int main(){
  /*(...)*/
 ciclo:
  //limpar tela
  printf("\nPara calculo de Tensao(resistencia*corrente) digite 1\n\nPara calculo de Potencia(tensao*corrente) digite 2\n\nPara calculo de Corrente(carga eletrica/tempo) digite 3\n\nPara calculo de Tensao de outra Maneira(trabalho/carga eletrica) digite 4\n\nPara calculo de Potencia de Outra Maneira(resistencia*corrente^2) digite 5\n\nPara calculo de Potencia de Outra Maneira(tensao^2/resistencia) digite 6\n\nDigite 7 para sair do Menu!\n\n");
  scanf("%d", &i);
  switch(i){
  /*(...)*/
   case 7:
    goto fim;
   default:
    printf("Valor Invalido!");
    break;
  }
goto ciclo;

fim:
return 0;
}
```

[Como usar switch em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282675/como-usar-switch-em-c)

Comment: Porque não um `do{ (...) }while( i  != 7);` ?

Comment: Sim, tambem podia ser claro, costumo programar mais desta maneira e penso que ter uma variavel extra para dar o break seja mais intuitiva, não sei, preferência minha

Comment: Visto que você declara a variável **extra** fora do ciclo `while` não faz muito sentido `if(val==1) break;`  e usar `while(1)`. Está a desperdiçar uma comparação sem necessidade e penso que não seja mais intuítivo. BTW não fui eu que dei nega, apenas estou tentado ajudar.Porém a pergunta bem merecia uma nega -.-'

Comment: Sim eu sei, eu costumo usar essas variaveis para depois ser mais facil no debug, eu posso editar. Merecia uma nega porquê? Há sempre a opção de fazer a sua resposta tambem.

Comment: Quando disse "nega" referia-me á pergunta e não á sua resposta.